# How to manage url in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I create project with Laravel 5.6.

I create this url:

`localhost:8000:/admin/products` (Products, Index page)

route:

```
$this->namespace('Products')->group(function () {
    $this->resource('products', 'IndexController');
});
```

I need create this url:

`localhost:8000:/admin/products/type` (Product type, Index page)

route:

```
$this->namespace('Products')->group(function () {
    $this->resource('products', 'IndexController');
    $this->name('products.')->group(function () {
       $this->resource('type', 'ProductTypeController');
    });
});
```

But in Url is: `localhost:8000:/admin/type` !

How to create this url ? `localhost:8000:/admin/products/type`

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to visit **'/admin/products/type'**, simply use

`Route::get('/admin/products/type', function(){
    return 'Hi';
});`

If you wish to create a resource controller for /../../type url, you can simply use

```
Route::resource('/admin/products/type', 'TypeController')}
```

It will redirect to the specific controller method based on the url. For more info. [Routing in Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing) and [Controller](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/controllers)